How to add an external email (group) as an AD guest user?
How to add an external distribution list or group email as a guest user in my AD?
Example: CompanyDL@anothercompany.com
Above is an example of an external DL. Can this be added as a guest user in my AD?

No. Everything in terms of groups has to be local. You may be able to setup a sync that syncs an external group and local group.

What do you mean by everything interms of group has to be local

Everyting in your ActiveDirectory has to be local. With Microsoft 365, you can setup a sync. In that case, it synchronises M365 groups with on-premise groups and then it creates a local group with a link to the M365 group to automatically make changes on both ends. In a group, you also need the users to be the same, so if this is for external contacts, then you most likely can't do it with sync anyway.

You can create a contact with the email address of the external distribution list. You can then email to that contact to auto-forward it to that distribution list. Is that what you want?

Basically I have SharePoint folder that I need to share with my customer's external email address. But that email is actually a distribution list and not a normal account. Customer uses that DL so I don't have to assign multiple users with permissions to the folder and customer can choose who will be in the DL.

In theory, you could just share a folder and specify that email address as external guest. An account is created in your sharepoint with that email address, and the welcome message is then sent to everyone. One of the persons in that DL should then do the login, and create a password. Now, everyone who knows the email address of the DL and the password can get in.

Azure AD doesn't allow adding such an email as guest
